# Remove custom user control from a parent

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, parent

I've create custom user control using Awesomium. Now I've add a button to remove the control. My code:

```
  private void _exitButton_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
  {
        try
        {
            Grid parent = this.Parent as Grid;
            parent.Children.Remove(_browser);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException ex)
        {
            _Status.Content = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

But it does not remove whole control from parent (I'm assuming that will be a grid). What is wrong in my code? Any help will be very appreciated

///EDIT:
Link do screenShot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2f5irkeqxn4nef/Zrzut%20ekranu%202014-08-04%2011.19.06.png

Comment: put a break point to line `parent.Children....` and see if parent is Grid or not? Does its *children* collection contain the *_browser*? If you get an exception what the message is?

Comment: I looked up to visual tree of WPF and it contains. Let me upload screenshot

Comment: Maybe you need to re render your control again to render all the child controls (I am guessing after removing the visual is still left on your screen!?) maybe call InvalidateVisual() after the remove line?

Comment: It still stays on screen.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint as suggested above and see if the control is actually removed from the collection after the remove line of code?

Comment: I put it. WPF Visualiser shows me that constrol still is childen of ```_gridMain```

Comment: I have a suspicion that the remove line is not working. Can you put a break point in the catch part as well and if any exception is being raise. Also if it is code behind, what is stopping you from directly referencing your grid with its name and removing the control from it. Like MyGrid.Children.Remove(control)?

Comment: Okay, It's because user control is in other class and namespace. Also, as you know this is user control, not always grid will be parent, and the name can be different.

Comment: I only suggesting this approach as there isnt enough information from the code snippet posting(and in all likely it looks like you are trying to remove something from code behind). In ideal scenario you should be binding an ICommand to your delete button and then removing your control from the collection in your viewmodel rather than trying to delete from code behind!